# Using the MongoDB C# Driver (2.0) how might you specify and UpdateDefinition that will ignore properties with null values

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Contact poco has 5 props - Id, FirstName, LastName, Phone, Email.  Phone and Email are initially null and they are not referenced by client - they are in poco for "future" use.  The UpdateDefinition specifies .Set constructs for each property but doing this will add Email and Phone to the document even though they are null - how do we avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that's not possible. We'd have to ask the authors, but it looks like this is a deliberate choice and I believe it makes sense. Even if you use `[BsonIgnoreIfNull]` and `[BsonIgnoreIfDefault]` on the field, an explicit `Set()` will still translate more or less directly to `$set`. The [`Set()` method is a very thin wrapper](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/src/MongoDB.Driver/UpdateDefinitionBuilder.cs#L1262) that will create a `BsonDocument` which is then sent to the server.

The thing is, if this was different, it'd mean that using `Set` with value `null` translates to a **`$unset`** which would seem really weird and counter-intuitive.

The key problem seems to be the use of a ton of explicit atomic operations - why don't you simply *replace* the document? In a document database, that is most straightforward approach, and `$set` really only makes sense if you have different writers to an object and you want to selectively update only one or two fields, or if the document seems to large to pipe back and forth so, again selectively, you only want to update a few fields. Using `$set` on the entire object seems useless to me. If you have an SQL background, remember that the query language is quite different in that SQL doesn't *have* a replace operation, it always uses explicit set statements.

**EDIT**: To solve this in an ***embedded array***, the `$` positional update operator will do the trick, so you can `$set` the entire embedded document:

```
db.customers.update(
   { "contacts.id" : contactIdToReplace },
   { $set: { "contacts.$" : { "email" : "foo", ... } } }
)
```

In C#, this translates to

```
collection.UpdateOneAsync(
  Builders<Customer>.Filter.Eq("Contacts.Id", contact.Id), 
  Builders<Customer>.Update.Set("Contacts.$", 
     new Contact { Email = null })).Wait();
```

With `[BsonIgnoreIfNull]` on the `Email` property in `Contact`, this will work as desired.

Comment: Great question and great response - the example I'm having issues with really concerns an element within an array.  For example - I have a "Customer" document with a "Contacts" key which is an array of contacts - each containing the properties I mentioned.  I suppose the best solution might be to "pull" and then "push" - this feels like the "replace" - only I'll have to do this in two steps - pull and then push?.  In my particular use case I'm looking to edit an existing contact and I don't want to pass the entire document across the wire.

Comment: Well, you didn't say that... I have working code that demonstrates this, but I can't access it in the next 10 hours or so.

Comment: Thanks! When I changed my UpdateDefinition to a single "$Set" like below it worked as desired!                                                                                                            var update = updateDefinition.Set("Contacts.$", contact);                                 Previously I had multiple .Set as in .Set("Contacts.$.FirstName).Set(....) Many thanks @mnemosyn